# SQL Server to split text by delimiter ( , ) into only 6 columns

Tags: sql

I'm facing an issue while dealing with long text in sql.

For example, I have this data

```
(26,Contacted,Hi, thank you for helping ,Alaa,Alaa,'2018-12-04 14:45:36')
```

the desired outcome:

```
ID            25
Status       Contacted
comment      Hi, thank you for helping
Updated_By   Alaa
Created_By   Alaa
Date_Created  2018-12-04 14:45:36
```

However this is what I get

```
ID            25
Status       Contacted
comment      Hi
Updated_By   thank you for helping
Created_By   Alaa
Date_Created  Alaa
```

which will be inserted into this table

```
ID int,
Status nvarchar(1000),
comment nvarchar(max),
Updated_By nvarchar(1000),
Created_By nvarchar(1000),
Date_Created DATETIME)
```

My insert statement as following

```
insert into xyz(ID,Status,comments,Updated_By,Created_By,Date_Created) 
select ID = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[0]'),
Status = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]'),
comments= JSON_VALUE(S,'$[2]'),
Updated_By = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[3]'),
Created_By = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[4]'),
Date_Created = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[5]')
FROM @dataset    
Cross Apply ( values ( '["'+replace(STRING_ESCAPE(records,'json'),',','","')+'"]' ) ) B(S)
```

@dataset is a table that contain the records

How can I split the text without splitting the comment part as well?

Comment: with `N'a string, that can, contain, like Shatner, commas'`?

Comment: yes the comment contains data that maybe with (,) but I don't want it to be split

Comment: nothing is going to split it; a single string value is stored in one column; maybe you could be a bit more specific about what problem you're experiencing, because: strings work fine

Comment: Enclose the values with doble quotes.

Comment: Please mention how you are trying to insert, either manually or any ETL process. If manually just post your insert statement, that would help to identify the issue

Comment: @JimMacaulay the quote choice may be dependent on the SQL variant, but OP says "SQL Server", and in SQL Server TSQL the string literal syntax is single-quotes

Comment: Done, I extract the data using XML api then save it in @dataset under records so it's manually

Answer (score 0):

String literals need to be quoted, i.e.

```
insert SomeTable (Id, Status, comment, Updated_By, Created_By, Date_Created)
values  (26,'Contacted',N'some comment that may contain '',''',
    'Alaa','Alaa','2018-12-04 14:45:36');
```

here noting that `'` surrounds string literals, a `N` prefix on that means "unicode" (although a non-unicode literal will be promoted to a unicode column without issue), and single-quotes inside the value need doubling, i.e. the `''`.

Note that if you're doing this from *code* rather than as a fixed SQL script, you should use parameters instead:

```
insert SomeTable (Id, Status, comment, Updated_By, Created_By, Date_Created)
values  (@id, @status, @comment, @updatedBy, @createdBy, @dateCreated);
```

adding parameters to whatever data-access API you're using.

Comment: I can't edit the values as they come from an API

Comment: @AlaaAljadani if the data is coming from an API and the values aren't fixed, then as I already said: use parameters - then you *don't have to* edit any values. What is the code that is wrapping this? If you can be more specific, people can help you more.